# ng2-summernote is not loading editor

Tags: angular, summernote

I am using `ng2-summernote` in my `angular2` project. Source: https://github.com/martinsvb/ng2-summernote

I added everything as per Readme file but but it showing empty `summernote`. 
Check my below source:

```
<ng2-summernote name="data2" ng-reflect-lang="cs-CZ" ng-reflect-name="data2" class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid" lang="cs-CZ">
  <div class="summernote"></div>
</ng2-summernote>
```

Comment: You can also post this issue: https://github.com/martinsvb/ng2-summernote/issues

Comment: @HassanFalahi, someone already reported same issue before 15 days. I commented if he got the solution.